# My question on PointSize usage is off-topic?

Tags: discussion

On my question concerning [how to control the PointSize of a dot on a plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61037/controlling-pointsize-in-a-regionplot) in version 10 of Mathematica got two close votes for being "off topic". However, neither of the closers made a comment saying why they thought it was off topic, so I am wondering why they would have thought it was off topic. Did they think the question was too basic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The close votes were cast for the following (standard form) reason:

> This question cannot be answered without additional information.
>   Questions on problems in code must describe the specific problem and
>   include valid code to reproduce it. Any data used for programming
>   examples should be embedded in the question or code to generate the
>   (fake) data must be included.

Briefly looking at your original post I see that you used things like `curve` and `point` without defining them.  Code examples should be self-contained when at all possible as otherwise answerers often have to first reconstruct your code before continuing.